# How do I use BeautifulSoup to search for elements that occur before another element?

Tags: django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup 4 with Python 3.7.  I have the following HTML ...

```
<tr>
    <td class="info"><div class="title">...</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="ls">
    <td colspan="3">Less similar results</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="info"><div class="title">...</div></td>
</tr>
```

I would like to extract the DIVs with class="title", however, I only want to find the ones that occur before the element in the table whose TD text = "Less similar results".  Right now I have this

```
elts = soup.find("td", class_="info").find_all("div", class_="title")
```

But this returns all DIVs with that class, even ones that have occurred after the element I want to screen for.  How do I refine my search to only include results before that particualr TD?

Comment: Is the "Less similar results" always defined in a `<tr class="ls">`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `tr:not(tr:has(td:contains("Less similar results")) ~ *) div.title`:

```
data = '''<tr>
    <td class="info"><div class="title">THIS YOU WANT ...</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="ls">
    <td colspan="3">Less similar results</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="info"><div class="title">THIS YOU DON'T WANT ...</div></td>
</tr>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.select('tr:not(tr:has(td:contains("Less similar results")) ~ *) div.title'))
```

Prints:

```
[<div class="title">THIS YOU WANT ...</div>]
```

**What does it mean?**

`tr:not(tr:has(td:contains("Less similar results")) ~ *) div.title`

Select `<div>` with class `title`, that is under `<tr>` which comes before `<tr>` that contains `<td>` with `"Less similar results"`.

Further reading:

**[CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Answer (score 2):

We can go the other way around, and focus on the `<tr class="ls">` first:

```
from bs4.element import Tag

ls = soup.find('tr', class_='ls')
elts = [td for tr in ls.previous_siblings
           if isinstance(tr, Tag)
           for td in tr.find_all('td', class_='info')]
```

This gives us:

```
>>> elts
[<td class="info"><div class="title">...</div></td>]
```

We thus first locate the `tr` with a `class="ls"`, and then we iterate over its previous siblings and look for `<td class="info">`s.

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
o = []
for td in soup.find("td", class_="info"):
    if td.get_text() == 'Less similar results':
        break
    for div in td.findChildren("div", class_='title'):
        o.append(div.get_text())

print(o)
```